# How to decorate a function that takes a tf.variable as a parameter with tf.function and most importantly using input signature

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a problem where I need to modify a variable inside a Tensorflow function. Then I need
to convert this function to a tensorflow graph.
The problem is that the size of the variable is not fix. Example: it can be either a tenosr of shape (3,) or (2,). This is why the function takes this variable as a parameter, so that it can modify it and return it.

Here is an example of a class that contains a function **call**, this function takes two arguments (x,v).
x is a Tf.tensor and v is a tf.Variable. v is assigned the the multiplication of x*v.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModule(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)])
  def __call__(self, x, v):
    v.assign(x*v, read_value=False)
    return v

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)
x = tf.constant([10,10])
v = tf.Variable(2*tf.ones_like(x), trainable=False)

module = MyModule()
module(x, v)
```

This works as expected in eager mode, but in graph mode I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

I know that it is because of the signature of tf.Variable.
My question is how can I specify the signature of tf.Variable given that the current one produces an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is one operation that can achieve what you want, however it is not listed in the public API. Beware that may not be the best practice.

You need `resource_variable_ops` which you can find under `tensorflow.python.ops`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import resource_variable_ops

class MyModule(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  @tf.function(input_signature=[
                                tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32), 
                                resource_variable_ops.VariableSpec(shape=[None], dtype=tf.int32)
                                ])
  def __call__(self, x, v):
    v.assign(x*v, read_value=False)
    return v

x = tf.constant([10,10])
v = tf.Variable(2*tf.ones_like(x), trainable=False)

module = MyModule()
module(x, v)
```

Comment: It worked!
Thank you very very much!
Can you tell me why this isn't a good practice.

Comment: Because everything under `tensorflow.python` is considered private. It can vary depending on the versions of TF. So depending your code on that, may not be the best practice everytime. If that solved the issue, you can accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another way to mutate values inside a function decorated with @tf.function or is this the only way.

Comment: Actually you can mutate values if you use `tf.Variable`, the problem was you want to specify `input_signature`. So, if you want to use input signature with `tf.Variable`, I think this might be the only way. Alternatively you can check `tf.TensorArray` which has `tf.TensorArraySpec`.

Answer (score 0):

you can complete it with a simple method.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        pass

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32)])
    def __call__(self, x, v):
        self.v.assign( x * v, read_value=False )
        return self.v

x = tf.constant( tf.random.uniform(shape=[2,1], maxval=3, dtype=tf.int32) )
v = tf.Variable([[1], [2]])
module = MyModule(v)

print( module(x, v) )

#############################################
x = tf.constant( tf.random.uniform(shape=[3,1], maxval=3, dtype=tf.int32) )
v = tf.Variable([[1], [2], [3]])
module = MyModule(v)

print( module(x, v) )
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1]
 [0]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor(
[[2]
 [0]
 [6]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: In summary why can't you just initialize self.v inside the constructor of the Class. Like this:
`self.v = tf.Variable([[1], [2]])`

Comment: It is faster when you do follow the objectives, the question intends to make the function that accepted a dynamic shape.

Comment: You are right.
Your answer can be better improved by defining an ampy variable inside the constructor.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have found:

```
class MyModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = tf.Variable([[]], shape=tf.TensorShape([None]*2), dtype=tf.int32)

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None]*2, dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None]*2, dtype=tf.int32)])
    def __call__(self, x, v):
      self.v.assign( x * v, read_value=False)
      return self.v
```

Defining tf.Variable inside the constructor of the model with empty values solved the problem.

Comment: How about target expectations ?
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[500, 1], dtype=tf.int32), tf.TensorSpec(shape=[2, 1], dtype=tf.int32)])
def __call__(self, x, v):
    self.w = tf.zeros([ x.shape[0] - v.shape[0], 1], dtype=tf.int32)
    self.w = tf.concat([v, self.w], 0)
    return self.w

Comment: I don't really understand what is the purpose of your code. Can your clarify it more.
But this code won't run in graph mode because of using ".shape"

Comment: The question is to use tf.Varialbes with specific shape input and output, it can return specific shape. 
From my answers you see me using [None} I just answer you that you can return specific shape.